# How to use multiple Stripe secret keys with stripe-node?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using [stripe-node](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) library. I need to interact with several stripe accounts, each one with their own secret key. What's the best way to do that?

Is there a way to specify the secret key for each request, like:

```
stripe.charges.create({
  auth: secret_key_1,
  ...
});
stripe.charges.create({
  auth: secret_key_2,
  ...
});
```

One workaround I thought of is simply instantiating a separate stripe instance for each account.

Answer (score 2):

As it states in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication?lang=node) you can set the `api_key` on a per-request basis like this:

```
stripe.charges.retrieve("ch_1AqjPcJWCk4FIh3mWQ3Hvmvi", {
  api_key: "sk_test_nra5nLtBVqMvXCoYROwWQFRG"
});
```

The only other alternative is to have multiple instances as already mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `stripe.setApiKey` before each request.

```
stripe.setApiKey(secret_key_1);
stripe.charges.create({
  ...
});

stripe.setApiKey(secret_key_2);
stripe.charges.create({
  ...
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be an issue if I'm doing multiple charges asynchronously?

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky Probably. You could set the key for the next request in the promise callback. It's either that or have multiple instances of stripe setup with different keys.

Comment: This is not working for me in version 4.24.0: `stripe.setApiKey is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

You can send apiKey in option object

```
create(
 params?: ChargeCreateParams,
 options?: RequestOptions
)
```

You can call

```
stripe.charges.create({
  {}, // ChargeCreateParams
  {
    apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
  }
});
```