# How to implement Stripe's per-request authentication?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have a [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) app (AWS Serverless, NodeJS), and I'm trying to use Stripe's per-request authentication in my project to create customers and payment intents. Doc referenced: https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication

When I use global authentication, it works:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_key');

const customer = await stripe.customers.create(
    {
      name,
      email,
    }
  );
```

But in per-request authentication, it fails with the message `Cannot read property "create" of undefined.`

```
const stripe = require('stripe');

const customer = await stripe.customers.create(
    {
      name,
      email,
    },
    {
      api_key:
        "sk_test_key",
    }
  );
```

Any advice would be helpful. Also, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517064/how-to-use-multiple-stripe-secret-keys-with-stripe-node), but no luck there as well.

Comment: your `const Stripe` starts with a capital `S` while when you call the function you are using lower case `stripe` 

Try `const stripe = require('stripe')`

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. In the code, they are both "stripe", with a lowercase "s". Changed the question.

Comment: I see, try using `const stripe = require('stripe')()` without passing any secret keys. Also, `api_key` is deprecated, try to using `apiKey` as the parameter name instead

Comment: @wsw it worked. Thanks!